# Get Audio files from raw folder instead of SdCard

Tags: android, media-player

I have seen this MediaPlayer [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/) and I wounder if someone helps me to set Audio files play directly from `Raw` folder instead of `/SdCard/`?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class SongsManager {
// SDCard Path

@SuppressLint("SdCardPath")

final String MEDIA_PATH = new String("/sdcard/");

private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

// Constructor
public SongsManager() {

}

/**
 * Function to read all mp3 files from sdcard and store the details in
 * ArrayList
 * */
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList() {
    File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);

    if (home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter()).length > 0) {
        for (File file : home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter())) {
            HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
            song.put(
                    "songTitle",
                    file.getName().substring(0,
                            (file.getName().length() - 4)));
            song.put("songPath", file.getPath());

            // Adding each song to SongList
            songsList.add(song);
        }
    }
    // return songs list array
    return songsList;
}

/**
 * Class to filter files which are having .mp3 extension
 * */
class FileExtensionFilter implements FilenameFilter {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return (name.endsWith(".mp3") || name.endsWith(".MP3"));
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is what you are looking for

Raw folder access

```
 Uri uri=Uri.parse("android.resource://" + this.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.test);
```

Sd card access

```
 final Uri uri=Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Video/tmn.wmv");
```

where your video are in Video folder of SDCARD

Set media player source to raw folder

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
Uri uri=Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.test);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this,uri);
```

Comment: Thanks brother (Jibran Khan), but could you please tell me how can I add it to the current SongsManager.java file ?

Comment: Check my edits on how you can set the source to media player from raw folder.

Comment: Not video files but they are audio.

    final String MEDIA_PATH = new String("/sdcard/");
    File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);